# Can Azure function GridTrigger be used along with CosmosDB input binding?

Tags: azure

I am a newbie to Azure functions.  I am having problem with the below code where CosmosDB binding is not working. If I remove CosmosDB, it works find; I am able to get messages thru eventGridEvent.  But as soon as I add CosmosDB, this piece of code fails.  I had tried different Collectors (IAsyncCollectory, IReadOnlyCollection, IReadOnlyList, IEnumerable, etc.) some of them compiles fine but when deployed to Azure portal it does nothing (msg: function not found).
I need to retrieve data from CosmosDb and save it to a Queue by using the message coming thru eventGridEvent. I can hardcoded  but that is not allowed for my project.  Any help will be appreciated team!

```
[FunctionName("TopicGridTrigger")]
public static void Run([EventGridTrigger()] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
[Queue("myqueuetest")] out string queueMessage, 
[CosmosDB("MyCarStore", "cars", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<MyCar> Items,
ILogger log
)
{
   //SOME CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the error you get? On the other hand, you are using an async collector but the funcion does not return a task.

Comment: Hi,  On Azure portal I get this message "Cannot find function TopicGridTrigger".  I had tried different collectors as described on original message. Yes, I am awared of the async. I had even used DocumentClient and not luck at all.

Comment: Did it work using the local Az Function Emulator? Cause that error probably is telling you that the host.json file deployed to azure does not include that function

Comment: When running the Emulator, it compiles and it even shows that it is running locally.  But to pass value I have to deploy it on azure portal.